# Store users choice data in my array temporarily

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, function

This is my form and below is a function. I need 3 functions, 1 to store data, 1 to save the data and 1 to show all stored data. How can I do all of these functions so they all correspond with each other.

NOTE: The user will be entering the data so it's the users choice data which would temporarily be saved. The user should be able to click on the buttons to function the function but how can I do the three functions properly.

```
<form name = "Music">

            <p>Input a Song Name, Artist, Collaborations, Duration or Album</p>

            <input type="text" name = "Song_Name" id= "Song_Name" size="20"> <br> 
            <input type="text" name = "Artist" id= "Artist" size="20"> <br> 
            <input type="text" name = "Collaborations" id= "Collaborations" size="20"> <br> 
            <input type="text" name = "Duration" id= "Duration" size="20"> <br> 
            <input type="text" name = "Album" id= "Album" size="20"> <br> 

            <input type="button" value = "Save" onclick = "Save()"> <br>
            <input type="button" value = "Search" onclick = "Store()"> <br>
            <input type="button" value = "Show_All" onclick = "Show_All()"> <br>
```

Save function:

```
var catalogue[];

function Save = Music.Song_Name.Artist.Collaborations.Duration.Album.Save{

            var SongName = document.getElementById('Song_Name').value;
            var Artist = document.getElementById('Artist').value;
            var Collaborations = document.getElementById('Collaborations').value;
            var Duration = document.getElementById('Duration').value;
            var Album = document.getElementById('Album').value;

        document.write("You have chosen "+ Song_Name + Artist + Collaborations + Duration + Album)
}
```

Comment: This is your first time with javascript? I ask because syntax is completely wrong.

Comment: Could you help me in writing the code properly?

Comment: How come your second button says "Search" but your function and description says "Store"?

Comment: What is the difference between Store and Save?

Comment: Yes I noticed that and I have changed it after I realised I posted it on here. The button "Search" includes the function "Search" now. Could you help me with what I acquire please.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend storing the values in an object rather than an array. It's much easier to work with when you have multiple, related pieces of data. Here's how it would work for Store and Show:

```
var catalogue;

function Store() {
    catalogue = {
        SongName: document.getElementById('Song_Name').value;
        Artist: document.getElementById('Artist').value;
        Collaborations: document.getElementById('Collaborations').value;
        Duration: document.getElementById('Duration').value;
        Album: document.getElementById('Album').value;
    }
}

function Show_All() {
    document.getElementById('Song_Name').value = catalogue.SongName;
    document.getElementById('Artist').value = catalogue.Artist;
    document.getElementById('Collaborations').value = catalogue.Collaborations;
    document.getElementById('Duration').value = catalogue.Duration;
    document.getElementById('Album').value = catalogue.Album;
}
```

How you handle the "Save" would depend on where you want to save it to, but the general idea would be that you would pass the catalogue value either directly into wherever you're saving it, or parse the properties of the catalogue object and pass each one in to wherever you're saving them.

Comment: I tried the function and it doesn't work, do I have to save the data first before the function can actually works? Because the idea is, I have to store data first. I want the stored data to appear on screen, maybe as a prompt.

Then I want to search for the data, so again maybe appear as a prompt  saying "You have searched for..." so and so.

The final part to show all data which was stored by the user. Again thanks for the code but if you can help me with this, this would be of much help!

Comment: I somehow missed your comment on this when you made it, and just now noticed it. Since it's been so long, I'm guessing you no longer need help with it. If you do, I think I'll need more details about what exactly you want to happen when each of the buttons is clicked on, to be able to provide any useful help.